# Using sessionstorage for saving dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, mode, sessionstorage

I successfully added dark mode to my site using
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lfv0jqL/)

JS:

```
$('#mode').change(function(){   

if ($(this).prop('checked'))
{
    $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
}
else
{
    $('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
}
});
```

However, when refreshing the page the theme switches back obviously.
I can't find out how to use sessionstorage to keep dark mode over the domain.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you require session storage be used? Could cookie or local storage work instead?

Comment: I don't mind how it is saved, I'm not the best in js and I have no idea what the best idea is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use local storage for storing the data

```
function darkmode(){
    $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
    localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
    }



function nodark(){
        $('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
        localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
        }

  if(localStorage.getItem("mode")=="dark")
        darkmode();
  else
    nodark();

$('#mode').change(function(){   

    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        darkmode();
    }
    else
    {
        nodark();
    }

});
```

Comment: Cookies are an obsolete approach to store certain data, since you don't want to send requests along with a lot of pointless data which is useless for the server...

Comment: When using this code the dark mode will be enabled by default, and when refreshing after changing to default theme it switches back to dark mode. also, I'm using a switch which is being set to default even if the dark mode is enabled. Is there an solution for that?

Comment: Hmmm, it does work in fiddle but does not seem to work in dreamweaver or my server after publishing it. The theme stays white after reloading

Comment: Try clearing the cache of your browser of your server and run this again

Comment: Nope, no result. I even tried it on my phone and another PC. after refreshing it just changes back to default theme

Comment: Add console.log(document.cookie);  to the code and tell me the result

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "console.log(document.cookie);". I have added that line to the dark-mode.js and retried. without result.

Comment: The  log will be shown only inside the  console.If you don't know about that ,you can try  alert(document.cookie) ;

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but I don't know exactly what you mean. Is it possible that we can move this discussion to a chat or I can host a clone of the site so you can take a look at it?

Comment: I have used the alert here http://jsfiddle.net/7Lfv0jqL/44/. Run this code in your browser and tell the details inside the popup

Comment: Oh I had it right then: It says: "__test=e91d2ab3d4ea4c4fb2e753a14c80b31d; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1117944057.1487512989; mode=light
"

Comment: what happens when you click the checkbox and reload

Comment: after changing theme to dark, and reload. it shows me exactly the same error.

Comment: I played some with the code, but couldn't get it working, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have used local storage instead of cookies.Check if it works

Comment: We made progress! The theme does indeed change and reloading will load the theme automatically. however, this only seems to work on the index page. on the other pages it doesn't even change theme anymore. However when I change the theme on any other page and then go back to index.html it will show the theme selected on the previous page.

Comment: Use seperate names for storing the light and dark themes for each page.For example you can use mode1 for the index page ,then mode2, mode3 etc for the folllowing pages

Comment: Update: I fixed it! it works now. Just have to find a solution for the html switch which switches back while the theme is still dark. any idea's? (I'm using this switch atm: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)